# Does an equivalent for netconf exist in the Cisco ASA world?

Tags: firewalls, cisco

I'm looking for a method to send instructions to a Cisco ASA without writing scripts to execute on the CLI over SSH. Cisco doesn't seem to support netconf or xml-pi on the physical ASAs (only their new 1000v series).

Are there any suggestions for an ASA API?

Answer (score 1):

To best of my knowledge , there are no Cisco API's for Physical ASA's . You need to do it via CLI or Cisco Security Manager or ASDM .

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if it helps.

Cisco has a shell that can be used for some automation.

As far as I know this exists only on CISCO Routers and Switches, **I don't know if in the latest ASA IOS the tcl shell has been implemented fully or partially.** (never used it on a ASA... ).

To chek if your IOS has the shell you only need to write **tclsh** in privilege mode.
This shell is the TCL shell where you can use TCL Scripting to automate some actions.

After that you can build the tcl scripts with the actions that you wish and you can make a simple webpage and activate https on your system to execute remotely the actions that you wish.

Plan correctly and implement the this with the appropriate security and you can have a better on-demand automation.

Some guides to scripting:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/6_x/nx-os/fundamentals/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_Fundamentals_Configuration_Guide_Release_6.x_chapter_01001.html

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/netmgmt/configuration/guide/nm_script_tcl.pdf